# Does IIS throw away the URL fragment on custom error pages?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, url-rewriting

I'm using the old 404-rewrite method on a certain site that is *tied to IIS6* *.

So if I enter

```
http://example.com/non-existent/path
```

it calls my error page like so

```
http://example.com/catch.aspx?404;http://example.com/non-existent/path
```

Great.

***Except*** if I call the page with a fragment, like

```
http://example.com/non-existent/path#with-fragment
```

I get the same result as above.  I can't find the fragment anywhere:

- Request.Url
- Request.Url.OriginalString
- Request.UrlReferrer
- Request.RawUrl
- headers, server variables, etc

This has come up because I want to resolve paths created by AJAX to their server-side versions.

Is there any way for me to retrieve the original path from my handler?

Thanks.

(*) Please don't suggest I change platform.  Obviously I would if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.
The portion of URL after # is never passed to the server per HTTP spec. Has nothing to do with platform.

To work with info after # in javascript you should look at Javascript History plugins/functionality. jQuery has history plugin, asp.net ajax and mvc ajax (partial views et al) have that. Mind you, it's not a very easy thing to implement, you have to get into undo/redo mindset.

It probably won't work if you are trying to handle 404's on the server - server doesn't know that there was something after #. Not sure what you want to do though, 404 handling, or "resolve paths created by AJAX"? What exactly is the goal?

Comment: Wow... you're right.  I had never tried to do this on *any* page before.  The goal is to handle URL's created by client-side navigation, like example.com/somepage#!some-other-page.  Facebook does this for example.  If you enter that URL, it will automatically redirect to some-other-page and get rid of the fragment.  I didn't realize that was being handled on the client side (so not strictly a redirect).

Comment: note that #! syntax is special for google - http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html . This tells google that it can put #!something in the querystring