# IIS URL Rewrite Match # in part of URL

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I can't get IIS to match a URL with a `#`. Instead It trims the URL at the `#`

```
/product name to match #1.html
^seeds/([A-Za-z0-9-_ #]+).html/?$
```

I've tried escaping it, to no avail.

Result from IIS is `/product name to match`

Any ideas?

N.B. whoever marked my question as answered elsewhere please read my question again.

Comment: no thats totally off topic from what I'm asking

Comment: You probably missed the first [linked topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19400135/1020526).

Comment: Yes I did, thanks for that. Damn so there is no way for me to make these links backwards compatable or 301 them to a new URL. Crazy. My only option is setting up physical files as that seems to work